# Displaying top 5 values in a TreeMap with given Strings

Tags: java, treemap

I have a TreeMap right now that holds 8 sets of , where it is sorted alphabetically based on the string. I basically need to display the top 5 sets based on their values (Integers). For example
The treeMap might look like this:

{A = 5, B = 1, C = 10, D = 16, E = 7, F = 2, G = 11}

I would need it to print out:

D = 16, G = 11, C = 10, E = 7, A = 5

I don't think I can do this directly from a treeMap, but I was wondering if anyone knew. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 8 sets of what? (you seem to have accidentally a word)

Comment: I have 8 setd in my map, 8 keys with their 8 values.

Comment: you mean you have 8 **entries** in your map right? `Set` have other meaning and is confusing here

Answer (score 0):

No, obviously it cannot be done by simply using a `TreeMap` as a `TreeMap` is ordered by `key`, not `value`.

You may consider maintaining a `MultiMap` (e.g. from [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) ) on the same time you maintain your original `TreeMap` (hence you have 2 Maps there.  You may better encapsulate them into a new class though) , which you use the number as key, and the string as value.  By using a `MultiMap` backed by a `TreeMap`, it should be trivial to find out first `n` entries with biggest number.

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian Shum mentioned, there is no way to do it simply by using a `TreeMap`.

However, if you're okay with straying away from `TreeMap`, you can [sort by value using a custom comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2581754/5635723), iterate over the results and print the first five entries. **Note that the linked answer sorts ascending, so you will have to switch the order of comparison to sort descending.**

Sort by value descending (taken and modified from the SO answer linked above):

```
import java.util.*

public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> Map<K, V> sortByValue( Map<K, V> map ) {

    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> list =
        new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>( map.entrySet() );
    Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>()
    {
        public int compare( Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2 )
        {
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo( o1.getValue() );
        }
    } );

    Map<K, V> result = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : list)
    {
        result.put( entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Print the first five entries:

```
import java.util.*

Map<String, Integer> treeMap = // init to {A = 5,B = 1,...}
Map<String, Integer sortedByValue = sortByValue(treeMap);

int i = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : sortedByValue.entrySet()) {
    if (i < 5) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
        i++;
    }
    else {
        // no need to keep looping once after we have printed the top 5 entries
        break;
    }
}
```